# Showing Crystal Report on a WPF Application(Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports, show, new-window

In Windows Form application, it was as trivial as Creating a Form and bind the RPT file to the Form.  Looks like this option isn't possible with WPF.

I would like to show a Crystal Report on a new Window when a button is clicked. How to achieve this with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using the Window Class:

See code below for demonstration

```
MyWindowType myReport = new MyWindowType(); // create a window, MyWindow is an User Control of type Window, that is it extends Window

MyCrystalReport myReport = new MyCrystalReport();
// Do necessary modifications to myReport such as Add Data and Send Parameters
CrystalReportViewer rptViewer = new CrystalReportViewer(); // Construct a ReportViewer
WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost(); // Create a WindowsFormsHost
rptViewer.ReportSource = myReport; // Add Report to ReportSource 
host.Child = rptViewer; // Add report viewer as child to host
myReport.reportGrid.Children.Add(host); // Add host to MainWindow, that is myReport in this example
myReport.BringIntoView();
myReport.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Visual Studio are you using? If VS2010, there is a WPF CrystalReportViewer available for download.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008.